# Android Layout Auto Complete fail when using custom component

Tags: android

In my layout I have a subclass of a TextView.

```
        <com.class.path.views.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD!"
        />
```

This works fine. My problem is that the "auto complete" doesn't work. If I remove the class path and just put TextView instead the "auto complete" works like a charm again.

This isnt a big issue but it is a bit annoying when you cant remember the *android:properties* that you need.

So my question is should this work? is it a documented bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and this is to be fixed in ADT 12 (current latest version is ADT 11).

> We've fixed a number of smaller issues in ADT 12 that don't deserve blog posts on their own, but here's a quick roundup:
>   ...
>   * Code completion inside a custom view layout has been improved
>   ...

Source: http://tools.android.com/recent/adt12bugfixroundup

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea as to when ADT 12 is coming out?

Comment: ADT 11 was released two weeks ago. My guess is that ADT 12 will be released in one month. But you can download ADT 12 preview right now: http://tools.android.com/

Comment: @inazaruk +1 for the detailed, immediate answer. Joakim, you should accept answers to your questions by clicking on the checkmark icon.